# Django class based views paginate_by as variable

Tags: django, listview

How can I pass "request" to ListView to use "paginate_by" as variable?

I have found many examples like this:

```
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = models.Car      
    template_name = 'app/car_list.html'  
    context_object_name = "car_list"    
    paginate_by = 10
```

I would like get paginate_by as variable from my user settings model "UserSettings"

I have tired use it in following way:

```
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = models.Car      
    template_name = 'app/car_list.html'  
    context_object_name = "car_list"
    user_settings = UserSettings.objects.get(user=request.user.id)   
    paginate_by = user_settings.per_page
```

but I've got error "name 'request' is not defined"

Answer (score 2):

You can add method [`get_paginate_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_paginate_by) to do what you need and use request from `self.request`.

The sample code would be

```
class CarListView(ListView):
  ...
  def get_paginate_by(queryset):
        user_settings = UserSettings.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id) 
        return user_settings.per_page
```

Handle the error conditions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a safe fallback:

```
class CarListView(ListView):
    model = models.Car      
    template_name = 'app/car_list.html'  
    context_object_name = "car_list"    
    paginate_by = 10
    user_settings = UserSettings


    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        """
        Try to fetch pagination by user settings,
        If there is none fallback to the original.
        """

        try:
            self.paginate_by = self.user_settings.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id).per_page
        except:
            pass
        return self.paginate_by
```

Or if you want to use this on different views, create a Mixin:

```
class UserPagination(object):

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        """
        Try to fetch pagination by user settings,
        If there is none fallback to the original.
        """
        try:
            self.paginate_by = self.user_settings.objects.get(user=self.request.user.id).per_page
        except:
            pass
        return self.paginate_by
```

Then:

```
class CarListView(UserPagination, ListView):
    model = models.Car      
    template_name = 'app/car_list.html'  
    context_object_name = "car_list"    
    paginate_by = 10
    user_settings = UserSettings
```

Comment: Thank you.It works but I probably have problem with method execution order. When I change per_page the value has changed but table still has old amount of rows. The refresh is needed. Is it possible to triger UserPagination method after per_page has been changed?

Comment: If you are using some short of ajax request while the user is viewing the results table then no you can't have the updated per_page without refreshing the request.